# Mapping Functions to Associations

Tags: data, curated-data, associations, data-structures

If I have the association matrix listed bellow and I want to apply:

```
DimensionReduce[dataSet["Blink"]]
{{-0.0143753, -1.3448}, {0.645649, 0.405197}, {2.34272, 
1.31409}, {0.265923, 0.333157}, {-4.10469, 
0.255392}, {-0.154232, -0.663612}, {-0.0495373, -1.30402}, \
{1.23877, -0.0628112}, {1.106, -0.472952}, {-1.27623, 1.54036}}
```

and then replace all of my "Blink" values with the corresponding reduced values listed above. I want to do this for each state

```
<|"Blink" -> {{-7.80207, -6.81625, -8.95471, -7.94497}, 
{-8.04093,-7.15899, -8.87598, -8.20657}, {-8.30509, -7.26396, -8.97337, \
-8.43762}, {-7.93339, -7.26834, -8.96581, -8.06195}, {-7.51735, \
-7.54408, -8.60107, -7.58897}, {-7.85602, -7.01129, -8.93354, \
-7.94467}, {-7.81115, -6.82194, -8.94245, -7.94546}, {-8.08047, \
-7.011, -8.95986, -8.18716}, {-8.00258, -6.94715, -8.99978, \
-8.12634}, {-7.78044, -7.82569, -8.95928, -7.86188}}, 
 "Brow" -> {{-6.87407, -7.6617, -7.61289, -6.8707}, {-6.96051, \
-7.85301, -7.7866, -6.98906}, {-6.81728, -7.58617, -7.55388, \
-6.84338}, {-6.99797, -7.81099, -7.71307, -7.03809}, {-7.15693, \
-7.98096, -7.7831, -7.22676}, {-7.21755, -8.15857, -7.89819, \
-7.19838}, {-7.49575, -7.12824, -8.8197, -7.47529}, {-6.90696, \
-7.66507, -7.5255, -6.87899}, {-6.85744, -7.58705, -7.75462, \
-6.86313}, {-6.77376, -7.61734, -7.63576, -6.82904}}, 
 "Control" -> {{-5.95623, -6.22505, -8.91221, -5.95269}, {-6.03934, \
-5.74061, -8.9441, -6.00019}, {-6.17787, -5.8216, -8.9672, -6.08643}, \
{-5.91856, -5.86446, -8.88035, -5.98493}, {-6.29312, -6.18381, \
-9.01361, -6.28984}, {-6.10166, -6.07776, -8.92354, -5.98715}, \
{-6.14962, -5.80242, -8.97278, -6.06053}, {-5.92913, -5.76531, \
-8.97248, -5.88653}, {-6.02622, -6.01878, -8.93221, -6.03248}, \
{-5.86525, -6.28864, -8.91767, -5.84206}}, 
 "Smile" -> {{-6.99006, -7.06889, -9.0568, -7.14185}, {-6.28371, \
-5.58937, -8.98667, -6.62768}, {-6.45543, -5.93095, -9.08733, \
-6.65501}, {-6.46983, -5.82567, -9.01648, -6.89222}, {-6.59885, \
-5.70165, -9.11828, -6.84112}, {-6.34537, -5.97214, -9.01509, \
-6.35281}, {-6.4589, -5.62745, -9.07188, -6.62343}, {-6.39873, \
-5.63368, -9.07097, -6.66046}, {-6.50042, -5.70267, -9.07739, \
-6.61835}, {-6.8984, -7.01631, -9.07822, -6.91803}}|>
```

Comment: You are not even trying... Take a look at your previous question's answer and lookup the documentation.

Comment: Ok I shall, will post an answer when I have figured it out.

Comment: You should take a look at `GroupBy` closely ;)